# What is the automatic memory management mechanism in Swift?

Tags: swift

Apple's Swift programming language performs memory management automatically.  Do they use a garbage collector for this or is it more like Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?  I can't find any mention of it in their docs.

Comment: [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_50)

Comment: How is the question too broad?  It is very specific.  Whatever, I got the answer I wanted, since this outrages so many nerds, just go ahead and close it.  I'm sure everyone else would rather RTFM to get the answer.

Comment: I'm seing a lot of questions closed or put on hold for reasons that decidedly are just random and do not apply. I wish I could downvote the censorship.

Comment: @AnalogFile There are often cases of excessive closing, but this really is a simple "look up the answer in the book" type question, not a coding problem.

Comment: @alcalde sure. Interestingly however the OP wrote that he did look it up in the book and did not spot it. It may be embarrassing for him not to have read the book carefully enough, especially given the extremely simple language (and I mean English) used in the book, but it's hardly less on topic than any explanation of, say, the C++ standard. Besides it certainly is not too broad and there are neither too many possible answers or too long answers. If the flagging system cannot express the reason to close the question either the flagging system need fixing or the reason is not a good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses ARC. From the programming guide (on iBooks):

> We simplified memory management with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).